# How to import JSON data using jQuery.get & jQuery.Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I've found a source that provides all world countries and cities but I never find any tutorials or topics talking about it even tho it's been published on Github !.

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json

Now I'm trying to search for countries and cities using jQuery & autocomplete, Please have a look at my code and see why it's not working properly?!

> https://codepen.io/ali-ramadhan/pen/ExwmMjJ

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<label for="state">Country/City:</label>
<input id="state" name="state" />

<script>
$("#state").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.getJSON(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json",
      {
        query: request.term
      },
      response
    );
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: For Only Country: https://codepen.io/valukiya07/pen/zYEwXxq

Answer (score 1):

Your request is based on static data and the response has a very complex structure. If you're looking for just the Country names, consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#state").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json",
        function(myData) {
          response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(Object.keys(myData), request.term));
        }
      );
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="country">Country:</label>
<input id="country" name="country" />
```

You can refer the this Demo: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

When the User enters a Country name, a request for the data is made. Since we can't ask the API to perform some action on the data, it is only a static JSON file, we must filter in after it arrives. As we're just looking for the Countries, we can get the Key names from the top level of the data. There is an Autocomplete Filter Utility that can help us filter the results into a single Array of data that is passed back to the `response` function.

In my opinion, this is a large amount of data to pass for each request. I would advise caching the JSON data when possible to help reduce calls. I suspect you will have more need of the data if you need both a Country and City combination. You either split the search into two fields or build a new data set that uses a Parent/Child relationship.

The following is a more complex method that allows the User to search by City. Searches are cached to help reduce the calls to the JSON data.

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
    },
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var li;
        if (item.category != currentCategory) {
          ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
          currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        if (item.category) {
          li.attr("aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  function formatData(data) {
    var format = [];
    $.each(data, function(country, cities) {
      $.each(cities, function(index, city) {
        format.push({
          label: city,
          category: country
        });
      });
    });
    return format;
  }

  var cache = {};

  $("#state").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 3,
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var term = req.term;
      if (term in cache) {
        resp(cache[term]);
        return;
      }
      $.getJSON(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json",
        function(results) {
          var fData = formatData(results);
          var result = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(fData, term);
          cache[term] = result;
          resp(result);
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).val(ui.item.category + "/" + ui.item.label);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete-category {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  margin: .8em 0 .2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="state">Country/City:</label>
<input id="state" name="state" />
```

References:

- https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories
- https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data
- https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache